# C++ - istream error flags

Tags: c++

I'm a Spanish computer engineering student and we have been asked in our C++ subject to do two classes for a later use. This both classes are date(Fecha) and string. To make sure that our classes are working right, we have been provided with two test-auto.cpp; that teachers made for us. The thing is that my date class has three failed tests; and I'm sure it's happening because the same problem: istream error flags.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVS9n.png

Following what is asked for: *"If the input is incorrect, cin must be marked with error state (fail) and the operator must throw an exception of type Fecha::Invalida".*

The exception is done and works fine, because it's used in other tests and I have no problem. The problem is that flag. This is what I've done with my input:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, Fecha& f){

    char cad[11];

    is.width(11); //limitamos la lectura a 10 caracteres
    is>>cad;

    f = Fecha(cad); //llamada anónima al constructor. La eficiencia es mayor que crear una variable Fecha

    if(!f.compruebaFecha())
        is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);


    return is;
}
```

Being *compruebaFecha()* a private method of my class date; and being implemented like this:

```
bool Fecha::compruebaFecha()const{

  int meses[12] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

  if(annio_ % 4 == 0 && (annio_ % 400 == 0 || annio_ % 100 != 0)) meses[1]++;
  if(dia_ < 1 || dia_ > meses[mes_-1]) return false;
  if(mes_ < 1 || mes_ > 12) return false;
  if(annio_ > Fecha::AnnoMaximo || annio_ < Fecha::AnnoMinimo) return false;


  return true;

}
```

I told my header file that the input is a friend method of the class; so I can use compruebaFecha() correctly.

The exception is thrown in my constructors; so that's why it's not appearing inside the istream method.

I'm PRETTY sure that the conditional into my istream method is not working correctly; but I don't know what to do to solve it.

Any ideas? If you need more code I'm up to give whatever I can so you can assist me.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I forgot completetly. This is one example that we have been provided with:

```
Fecha f; // fecha de hoy
try {
  std :: cin >> f;
  std :: cout << "OK, la fecha es: " << f << std::endl;
}
catch(const Fecha::Invalida& e) {
  if (! std :: cin . fail ())
    std :: cerr << "Mal hecho, cin debe estar en fallo" << std::endl;
  std :: cerr << e.por que() << std::endl;
  std :: cin . clear ();
  if ( f != Fecha())
    std :: cerr << "Mal hecho, la fecha no se ha leido bien y debe ser "
    "la de hoy." << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT2:** Added the constructors:

```
Fecha::Fecha(const char* fechaCadena){

  if(3 != sscanf(fechaCadena,"%d/%d/%d",&dia_, &mes_ , &annio_)) throw Fecha::Invalida("La fecha introducida no es valida");

  *this = Fecha(dia_, mes_, annio_);
}
```

And this is the call to the other constructor:

```
Fecha::Fecha(int dia, int mes, int annio) : dia_(dia), mes_(mes), annio_(annio){

  std::time_t tiempoCalculado = std::time(0);
  std::tm* tiempoDescomp = std::localtime(&tiempoCalculado);

  if(dia == 0) dia_ = tiempoDescomp -> tm_mday;
  if(mes == 0) mes_ = tiempoDescomp -> tm_mon + 1;
  if(annio == 0) annio_ = tiempoDescomp -> tm_year + 1900;

  if(!compruebaFecha()) throw Fecha::Invalida("La fecha introducida no es valida");
}
```

**EDIT3**: Added copy assignment:

```
 const char* Fecha::cadena() const{

 struct tm* tiempo;
 time_t cal;

 time(&cal);
 tiempo = localtime(&cal);

 tiempo->tm_year = annio_ - 1900;
 tiempo->tm_mon = mes_ - 1;
 tiempo->tm_mday = dia_;

 mktime(tiempo);

 const char* diaSemana[] = {"domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado"};
 const char* nombreMes[] = {"enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"};
 static char salida[36];

 sprintf(salida, "%s %2d de %s de %.4d", diaSemana[tiempo->tm_wday], dia_, nombreMes[mes_ - 1], annio_);

 return salida;
}
```

**EDIT4:** I add one of the tests that fail:

```
FCT_TEST_BGN(Fecha - Extraccion: fecha no valida) {
  istringstream is("90/20/4000");
  Fecha f;
  try {
is >> f;
    fct_chk(!"Se esperaba una excepción Fecha::Invalida");
  }
  catch(Fecha::Invalida) {
fct_chk(is.fail());
is.clear();
  }
  Fecha_chk_eq(f, diaSistema, mesSistema, annoSistema);
}
FCT_TEST_END();
```

Comment: Why do you create a new object of type `Fecha` within your operator? That doesn't make sense. You already have a `Fecha` object passed as an argument to the operator. The comment which says *"La eficiencia es mayor que crear una variable Fecha"* (= "efficiency is greater than creating a Fecha variable") also sounds quite nonsensical. And you do not show us what the `Fecha` copy assignment operator does, exactly.

Comment: I'm adding the copy assignment so you can see what it does. GIve me a second.

Comment: And the `Fecha` constructor which takes a `char*` argument. In fact, just post an MCVE, please.

Comment: Done, added all you asked for.

Comment: You should have tested your project before submitting it. Why discover that ithe code doesn't work at the least appropriate moment? Yoy seem to be surprised that failbit is never set. Why? In which cases should it be set?

Comment: Imagine that you write a date like: "40/30/9000". That's when the failbit should be set to true. It's more; if I test it with an int type state and initialize it with the value 1; and writing an if statement which condition is state == 1; it works. But yeah, that's not the condition I'm looking for. By the way, thank you a lot for taking your time in answering me. I appreaciate it a lot.

Comment: What else should happen when you write a date like  "40/30/9000"? Hint: you have already written an answer to this question, it's spelled out in your post, several times. If you have trouble figuring this out, use your debugger to step through your program line by line.

Comment: Wait @n.m. , I'm thinking. Maybe the exception is being thrown BEFORE the failbit is changed? Debugger will tell I guess.

Comment: Well it is thrown from the constructor, and the constructor is called before setting failbit, so...

Comment: Yup got it! Now its working fine. Thank you A LOT man. I own you one @n.m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completetly changed my istream method. This is the new code:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& is, Fecha& f){

   char cad[11];

   is.getline(cad, 11);
   try{

    f = Fecha(cad);
   }catch(Fecha::Invalida&)

    is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    throw Fecha::Invalida("La fecha introducida no es valida");
   }

   return is;

}
```

Now the statement of **compruebaFecha()** is done correctly; so if an exception is thrown inside the constructor, it will be catch in the istream method, setting the failbit to error state and throwing the exception that I need.

Additionally, I modified the *friend* field into the header of ***fecha.hpp*** for istream, because I don't use any private methods, so it's unnecesary.

Thank you a lot for your answers!